# MG ZS 180 - overheating clutch

Tags: clutch, overheating, mg, mg-zs, zs-180

So I got a new (well 2004) MG SZ 180 the other day and it turns out there is a small issue with it. After using the clutch in stop/start traffic, changing gear gets harder and harder until I end up either stuck in or out of gear. This can happen after just a mile or so of heavy traffic where 1st gear and reverse can get jammed completely.

I put the car in neutral at lights, junctions etc and even go as far as to coast up to light if I see it is red to reduce usage.  This is my 5th car and 2nd "sporty" car where I have never had clutch issues before.

I have just had the master and slave replace so any suggestions would be helpful.

**UPDATE:**

after looking at the metal mount for the slave I can see come movement when using the clutch but it is about the same when hot or cold.

is it possible to get a mounting bracket?

Comment: What was the reason for changing the master/slave? Or was this the issue in the first place which caused you to change them?

Comment: Some light reading on the subject suggests there is a plastic bracket which holds the slave cylinder in place, and is a weak point. If that is the case, then it could weaken and flex as it heats up, causing the symptoms you describe. The same reading suggests there are metal replacements available.

Comment: I also read similar things and thought a new Master Slave would do all that.  I have also has a quick look at the slave and it look like it is bolted to a metal plate but there is some movement when pressing the clutch.  it wound like I am looking in the right place, right?  I am avoiding a new clutch kit due to money.